# How to configure shared Internet connection + switch + router setup?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, switch

I have access to a shared Internet connection (~100Mbps) via ethernet wall jack in my apartment. Since I have a 54Mbps router, I would like to add a gigabit switch before the router so that I can have 100Mbps on my desktop via ethernet cable and then use router/WAP for my laptop and cellphone. Since the switch is a dumb or an unmanaged one, I cannot configure the DHCP/gateway on it and I assume that is why I do not have internet connection on either desktop or laptop through switch or router. I tried some similar questions but they do not exactly match this setup and purpose.

Is there anything I can configure on the router to overcome this issue? Or any other possible solutions?

[image]

**Edit:**
 1. The desktop and laptop fail to obtain IP address.
 2. They can obtain IP address if directly connected to wall jack.
 3. Manually configuring IP settings does not provide internet connection (same IP configuration when directly connecting to wall jack.

Comment: Please clarify "do not have internet connection". Does the computer fail to obtain an IP address via DHCP? (Do you know for sure that the ISP supports DHCP?) Or does it receive an IP address but is unable to ping other IPs? Or is it able to ping IPs but not domain names? Or is it able to ping domain names but not to visit websites?

Comment: I edited the question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the switch is a dumb or an unmanaged one, I cannot configure the DHCP/gateway on it and I assume that is why I do not have internet connection

No. It's a switch, not a router. The gateway configuration you've seen on managed switches is purely for the switch *itself* (i.e. for the management interface) and doesn't affect the computer's packets going through it. In other words, your computer will be talking directly with the ISP's gateway instead, no matter the type of the switch.

> I do not have internet connection on either desktop or laptop through switch or router

Try a different switch. Also, try connecting the computer directly without using a switch at all.

If you're completely sure that the switch is working properly, check whether the desktop and/or the router are at least able to obtain IP addresses from your ISP.

If they're configured to use DHCP but don't receive an address, it's possible that the Ethernet port only allows a single device (MAC limit), or requires a specific MAC, or requires PPPoE or 802.1X.

> Is there anything I can configure on the router to overcome this issue?

With your current topology, nothing you configure on the router can affect the PC. (Besides, you specifically wanted to *bypass* the router, didn't you?)

> Or any other possible solutions?

Put the switch *after* the router. Your router isn't "54 Mbps";  it's marketed as having 54 Mbps *Wi-Fi* (presumably 802.11g), but this says nothing about its Ethernet connection speed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It clarifies many aspects of the problem and I got my answer. I appreciate your detailed answer. Communities like SuperUser need more people like you, whom we can learn from, you provide an answer and provide many more details to learn. Thanks again